# Oracle procedure 'with query' insert into table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, common-table-expression, with-statement

I have created an Oracle SQL query in TOAD which works fine.  I now need to put this in a procedure.

The query has to create two counts based on different criteria (I have used With Select) and insert these plus a date and location to a table.

The query that works is

```
with
Selected_animals as 
(   SELECT  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY' ) as Report_Date,
           loc.name location,
           count(rran.id) as Count_exported
    FROM   rr_animals rran,
           contact con,
           locations loc,
           names nam
    WHERE  con.connum = rran.connum
    AND    con.loc_id = loc.id
    AND    con.connum = nam.connum
    AND    nam.name_type = 'STAND'
    AND    nam.dob IS NOT NULL
    AND    rran.sex IS NOT NULL
    AND    rran.web_display = 'Y'
    AND    rran.web_description IS NOT NULL
    AND    rran.visit_end_date IS NULL
    AND    con.loc_id IS NOT NULL
    AND    con.datedl IS NULL
    AND    rran.hold_user IS NULL
    AND    rran.assess_status IS NULL
    AND    EXISTS (SELECT rrim.id
                   FROM   rr_images rrim
                   WHERE  rrim.image_type = 'KENNEL'
                   AND    rrim.rran_id = rran.id
                   AND    DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(rrim.image_object) >0
                   AND    rrim.image_object IS NOT NULL)
    group by loc.NAME ),

total_animals as 
(select vbav.sitename as location,
       count(vbav.rran_ID) as Count_available

from v_bx_all_animal_visits vbav
where visit_end_date is null
and concat != 'DELTD'
and concat != 'DSCD'
group by vbav.sitename)

select Total_animals.location,
       Selected_animals.Report_date,
       Selected_animals.count_exported,
       Total_animals.count_available

from Selected_animals, total_animals
where total_animals.location = selected_animals.location(+)
```

I have looked at several ways that seem to write the procedure but nothing seems to work. Including which was added under the CREATE or REPLACE and before BEGIN:

```
(   o_location out bx_webstats_export_available.LOCATION%TYPE,
       o_date out bx_webstats_export_available.REPORT_DATE%TYPE,
       o_exported out bx_webstats_export_available.COUNT_EXPORTED%TYPE,
       o_available out bx_webstats_export_available.COUNT_AVAILABLE%TYPE   )
```

Also added after the last where statement and before End:

```
INSERT INTO bx_webstats_export_available(location, report_date, count_export, count_available)
       values (Total_animals.location,
       Selected_animals.Report_date,
       Selected_animals.count_exported,
       Total_animals.count_available);
```

Can anyone help me get this query in a Procedure please?

This is the first time I have written a Procedure from scratch and I'm struggling with it.

Many thanks,

Comment: What you tried, what difficulty you faced

Comment: I've tried compiling the this as a Procedure and a Package, both with no success.  As a Procedure it doesn't like the Begin and the error is '(S41) Expecting:    (    .   AS  AUTHID  IS  TIMESTAMP  WRAPPED'.  As a Package it doesn't like the first count statement, and the error is 'PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected'  To be honest I'm not sure how to resolve these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it you're trying to do? Insert the results of that select into a table? If so, the following ought to suffice:

```
create or replace procedure your_proc_name
as
begin
  insert into bx_webstats_export_available(location, report_date, count_export, count_available)
  with selected_animals as (select to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY' ) as report_date,
                                   loc.name location,
                                   count(rran.id) as count_exported
                            from   rr_animals rran,
                                   contact con,
                                   locations loc,
                                   names nam
                            where  con.connum = rran.connum
                            and    con.loc_id = loc.id
                            and    con.connum = nam.connum
                            and    nam.name_type = 'STAND'
                            and    nam.dob is not null
                            and    rran.sex is not null
                            and    rran.web_display = 'Y'
                            and    rran.web_description is not null
                            and    rran.visit_end_date is null
                            and    con.loc_id is not null
                            and    con.datedl is null
                            and    rran.hold_user is null
                            and    rran.assess_status is null
                            and    exists (select rrim.id
                                           from   rr_images rrim
                                           where  rrim.image_type = 'KENNEL'
                                           and    rrim.rran_id = rran.id
                                           and    dbms_lob.getlength(rrim.image_object) >0
                                           and    rrim.image_object is not null)
                            group by loc.name),
          total_animals as (select vbav.sitename as location,
                                   count(vbav.rran_id) as count_available
                            from   v_bx_all_animal_visits vbav
                            where  visit_end_date is null
                            and    concat != 'DELTD'
                            and    concat != 'DSCD'
                            group by vbav.sitename)
  select total_animals.location,
         selected_animals.report_date,
         selected_animals.count_exported,
         total_animals.count_available
  from   selected_animals, total_animals
  where  total_animals.location = selected_animals.location(+);
end your_proc_name;
/
```

If not, then please explain a bit more about the requirements you're trying to satisfy.

Comment: Hi, yes, just trying to insert the results into a table.  Your procedure above worked perfectly.  Many thanks.